# How can I use Linq to create an IEnumerable based on line breaks in a string?

Tags: c#, linq

I have some C# code in a string that looks like this:

```
content = 'var expData = 
                        details.Select(x => x.Explanation.TextWithHtml).ToList();
var score = resData.SequenceEqual(ansData);
var explanation = "";';
```

How can I make it so the code is converted to the following using LINQ?

```
<td>01</td><td>var expData = 
                  details.Select(x => x.Explanation.TextWithHtml ).ToList();</td>
<td>02</td><td>var score = resData.SequenceEqual(ansData);</td>
<td>03</td><td>var explanation = "";</td>
```

Comment: So, you want to take everything inside `` and split it by ;? then numerate every line with <td>?

Comment: No I need to split on line feed and then add an index that increments with each new line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like:

```
var lines = text.Split(new[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
                .Select((line, index) => 
                    string.Format("<td>{0:00}</td><td>{1}</td>",
                       index + 1, EscapeHtml(line)));
```

You'd need to write `EscapeHtml` though - you don't want tags in your C# code to still end up as tags in the HTML!

Comment: Won't the index be zero-based?

Comment: @Michael: Thanks, will fix that.

Comment: @Jon - I tried this but I am getting some errors. First it complained about "\r\n" saying: Error 3 The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments. Then there's a problem with EscapeHtml which it does not seem to recognize. Any ideas what could be wrong. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Gemma: As I said, you'll need to implement `EscapeHtml` yourself, or find another implementation. Will fix the `string.Split` call.

Comment: Wouldn't `HtmlUtility.HtmlEncode` do the trick, in conjunction with `string.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />")`?

Comment: @neontapir: Possibly. I haven't checked. My point is that *something* needs to be done, and that's away from the main direction of this question.

Comment: @Jon - Sorry I didn't quite understand what you meant "implement myself". I will look into it. Thanks.

Comment: @neontapir - How would you suggest I code up your suggestion? I'm not sure how I could fit that into Jon's suggestion.

Comment: It's untested, but something like `var lines = text.Split(new[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
                .Select((line, index) => 
                    string.Format("<td>{0:00}</td><td>{1}</td>",
                       index + 1, HtmlUtility.HtmlEncode(line).Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>"));`

Comment: Thank you, Jon, I didn't realize that HtmlEncode would handle newlines. See, I learned something too. :)

Comment: @neontapir: No, my point is that we've already split the data into single lines, so there won't *be* any newlines.

Comment: Oops, I see that now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

This should work, you can get the index from [`Enumerable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx):

```
IEnumerable<String> code =
    content.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)
           .Select((line, index) => 
                string.Format("<td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td>", 
                    (index + 1).ToString("D2"), line));
```

[How to: Pad a Number with Leading Zeros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048.aspx)

Comment: Why would you want to remove empty lines? If I'm reading source code, I would want to preserve the lovely empty lines inserted for readability.

Comment: @Jon: Good point, corrected :) If OP against expectation needs to remove the empty lines(or white-spaces at start/end): you just  have to change `StringSplitOptions.None` to `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`.

Comment: @Tim - I would like to keep the empty lines.